# Pandas Float Comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

How does Pandas store floats for comparison sake? I ran as simple check for a value and it returned what I expected but the result is not the same as my query / comparison:

Why aren't the values of each time epoch the same?

I tried rerunning this by first casting the column as `int` but then the comparison brought up nothing.

Comment: You know how most floating-point operations involve rounding? That includes even integer-to-float conversion. Your int is getting rounded.

Comment: don't use float for timestamps. use int64 (that's how pandas stores Timestamps under the hood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your floats are in nano-seconds since epoch, so to convert try this:

**Code;**

```
df.time = df.time.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1484314274417920512., 1484314274417620224.],
                  columns=['time'])
print(df)

df.time = df.time.astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
           time
0  1.484314e+18
1  1.484314e+18
                           time
0 2017-01-13 13:31:14.417920512
1 2017-01-13 13:31:14.417620224
```

**But:**

The problem likely came about when you converted from the original data source.  Converting the int64 to float64, has already lost some precision, so just converting it to nano-seconds, could very well still not do what you need.  Somethings that could be done:

1. Perform the original conversion directly to int64 so as not to lose precision.
2. If nano-seconds are not needed then round the timestamps to micro-seconds or milli-seconds.

Comment: Thing is I am populating my dataframe row by row, and the time is coming from my data source as an int but pandas forces it to a float for some reason, no matter what I try. I've tried np.int64(<value>), long(<value>), nothing. Pandas returns float64 for both.

Comment: Found the issue, I was populating my dataframe row by row  using `.loc` and it was forcing all numeric values to be of type `float64` regardless if my values were integers. My workaround was converting these integers to strings so pandas would leave them alone then change them back using `.astype(int)`